# When could sizeof(size_t) and sizeof(ptrdiff_t) differ?

Tags: c++

When could `sizeof(size_t)` and `sizeof(ptrdiff_t)` differ?

Is there any real-world example of this?

---

Note, I know that all the standard says about these types that they are implementation defined. But all the implementations I know, `sizeof(size_t)` and `sizeof(ptrdiff_t)` equals. Maybe for some weird (or not so weird) reason, they could differ.

It seems, that `sizeof(ptrdiff_t)<sizeof(size_t)` is not a very useful case, as pointer arithmetic would be very limited for large arrays.

The other case, `sizeof(ptrdiff_t)>sizeof(size_t)` could be slightly useful, as all pointer subtraction would be defined on arrays (if there is a larger array than `PTRDIFF_MAX`, pointer subtraction would be defined for all distant elements, contrary to the usual case when `sizeof(ptrdiff_t)==sizeof(size_t)`). Is there any real implementation which does this? Does this approach has any other useful properties?

Comment: Looking inside gcc source code, it seems that` __SIZE_TYPE__` is defined as `unsigned long int` and `__PTRDIFF_TYPE__` as `long int`. So there is good chance that on all possible gcc targets `ptrdiff_t` is the signed version of `size_t`. I would use this has a strong hypothesis in my code base, and check it with a static_assert. If the static_assert fires, either the hardware or compiler is wrong :)!!

Answer (score 3):

A reasonable case would be the classic 8086. With array sizes limited to 64K segments, `size_t` can be 16 bits. However, to support a `ptrdiff_t` with a 128 kB range (-64kB to +64kB), you'd need 17 bits.

The problem here is that the pointer type isn't a trivial byte counter which wraps around after 64 kB.

---

Here's an excerpt from `stddef.h` of Borland C++ 3.1:

```
#if     defined(__LARGE__) || defined(__HUGE__) || defined(__COMPACT__)
typedef long    ptrdiff_t;
#else
typedef int     ptrdiff_t;
#endif

typedef unsigned size_t;
```

So, if the memory model is large, huge, or compact (these memory models mean that data can be larger than 64KiB), then `sizeof(ptrdiff_t)` is 4 , while `sizeof(size_t)` is always 2.

Comment: I've added an example. It would be interesting to know why BC++3.1 does this, though. Maybe there was no restriction back then, that arithmetic can only be done on pointers which point into the same object?

Comment: @geza: AFAIK, it's always been a Standard restriction, not necessarily an implementation restriction.  Note that "Undefined Behavior" includes "you can do the arithmetic, but the outcomes are wonky". Doing arithmetic between two unrelated 8086 pointers might give you a 32 bits result, which should be interpreted as a 16:16 offset. Within a single array, the segment difference would always be zero, so the 16:16 result could still be interpreted as a single 32 bits value with the top bits all 0 or 1 (depending on whether you took a forwards or backwards difference).

Comment: BC++3.1 is from 1992/3, pre-standard era. Maybe this rule didn't exist back then (I don't know how C++ was specified before the standard)

Comment: @geza: This stuff is inherited from C89.